# React-filepond external CSS is not being applied. I suspect it's a webpack issue

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

This is beating my head in. I'm using react-filepond module in my react app, but the external CSS is not being applied. The module works but has no style. I suspect it's a loader issue in webpack but I'm still learning webpack and probably missed something. Thanks!

Here are the imports as per react-filepond:

```
import { FilePond } from 'react-filepond';
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.css';        // located in node_modules
```

Here's my webpack.config.js.
**I'm using webpack 3.12.0**

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', 'jsx', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['react']
            },
        exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: () => [
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    "> 1%",
                    "last 2 versions"
                  ]
                })
              ]
            }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
    }
  ]
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
},
plugins: [
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for others wondering about this.

**Issue**: I am using CSS modules in react (note the line modules:true in the configuration of my css-loader in my webpack-config.js

The external react module I was trying to use does NOT use CSS modules.

**Solution**:
create a second rule for external CSS. Thus I have one for my CSS (as in the source above) and then I added this rule:

```
  {
    /* External CSS from node_modules */
    test: /\.css$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    loader: [
        require.resolve('style-loader'),
        {
            loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
            options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                minimize: true,
            },
        }
    ]
  },
```

Most importantly, I did NOT turn on CSS Modules

And then, in my other CSS rule, I added:

```
    exclude: /node_modules/,
```